# ANTLR v4 signed integer rule

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

in ANTLR4 grammar for minijava example I want to parse signed integers by following rules:

```
IntegerLiteral:IntegerSign? DecimalIntegerLiteral;
fragment
DecimalIntegerLiteral:DecimalNumeral IntegertypeSuffix?;
fragment
IntegerSign:'+'|'-';
fragment
IntegertypeSuffix:[lL];
fragment
DecimalNumeral:'0'| NonZeroDigit(Digits?| Underscores Digits);
fragment
Digits:Digit(DigitsAndUnderscores? Digit)?;
fragment
Digit:'0'| NonZeroDigit;
fragment
NonZeroDigit:[1-9];
fragment
DigitsAndUnderscores:DigitOrUnderscore+;
fragment
DigitOrUnderscore:Digit| '_';
fragment
Underscores:'_'+;
```

but in parsing it get errors due to expression rule:

```
expression:expression PLUS expression # addExpression
```

[image]

how should I avoid this conflict?

Comment: It would help if you'd show more of your grammar.  Some of the rules pictured in your parse tree are not represented in the grammar snip you've shown.  Also, typically negation is written as a type of unary expression ranked among the other expression types your grammar contains.  This avoids conflicts between `-` subtraction and `-` negation.

Comment: No longer interested by help ? It would help if you'd show more of your `expression` rule.